# Rails Routes to return certain criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

```
$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.1
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
```

I've been using rails for about a month now, and am attempting to do a simple json api.   I have most of it working, but am having trouble with returning custom data based on relationships.

Gem File ( For reference ):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :docgi
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'rspec-its', '~> 1.2.0'
gem 'unicorn', '~> 4.9.0'
gem 'kaminari' # adds pagination to ActiveModels
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'simple_token_authentication', '~> 1.9.1'
gem 'cancancan'

group :development do
  gem 'quiet_assets', '~> 1.1.0'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.5.0'
end
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4.4'
  gem 'capybara-email', '~> 2.4.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.8.0'
end
```

As you can see with the gem file, I am using mongo through mongoid.  Then I have my user model:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  has_many :posts

  validates :email, presence: true,
            uniqueness: true,
            format: {
                with: /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\Z/
            }
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :telephone, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :gender, presence: true
  validates :dob, presence: true
  validates :photo_url, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :trackable, :validatable
  ## Token Authenticatable
  acts_as_token_authenticatable
  field :authentication_token

  ## Profile
  field :name,               type: String, default: ""
  field :gender,             type: Boolean, default: 0
  field :dob,                type: Date
  field :telephone,          type: String
  field :username,           type: String
  field :photo_url,          type: String
  field :last_action,        type: Time
  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              type: String, default: ""
  field :encrypted_password, type: String, default: ""

  ## Trackable
  field :sign_in_count,      type: Integer, default: 0
  field :current_sign_in_at, type: Time
  field :last_sign_in_at,    type: Time
  field :current_sign_in_ip, type: String
  field :last_sign_in_ip,    type: String

  ## Indexes
  index({ email: 1, username: 1 })
  index({ gender: 1, dob: 1, telephone: 1, posts: -1})

end
```

And the relationship that we've got associated here is the `has_many :posts`

Now I know that I can return all of them like so:

```
user = current_user
    render json: user.as_json(include: :posts), status: :created, location: @user
```

This works, it'll add the posts to the result set.  What I'm not exactly sure how to do, and this is the question here, is how to return specific results based on criteria.

For instance, I have a route where I want to grab the user, but only want to grab their last post.  And another route where I want to grab the user and all of their posts, but have the posts sorted newest to oldest over the span of the last 24 hours and I'm just not quite sure how to do that properly.

An example result set that I'm looking to achieve:

```
{
_id: "5548245663686f2a58030000",
authentication_token: "KG6qksJaUzKwU7aZxt94",
created_at: "2015-05-05T02:00:54.467Z",
dob: null,
email: "sjors1@purpledunes.com",
gender: false,
last_action: null,
name: "",
photo_url: null,
telephone: null,
updated_at: "2015-05-05T02:00:54.467Z",
username: null,
posts: [ ... ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the action belonging to the route where you want to grab the user and their last post, you could do this:

```
last_post = current_user.posts.last
render json: last_post.to_json
```

For your other route (where you want to grab the user and all of their posts from the last 24 hours sorted descending) you could try this:

```
posts = current_user.posts.where('created_at >= ?', 1.day.ago).order created_at: :desc
render json: posts.to_json
```

**Update**

You could take a look at [ActiveModal::Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) to try to solve your problem elegantly. You could for instance create a `UserSerializer` which looks as follows:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :last_post, :posts_from_last_day # and whatever else you want to be included

  has_many :posts

  def last_post
    object.posts.last
  end

  def posts_from_last_day
    object.posts.where('created_at >= ?', 1.day.ago).order created_at: :desc
  end
end
```

In your controller you would than have something like:

```
render json: current_user, serializer: UserSerializer
```

As an extra, you could even create a `scope` or method in your `Post` model which removes the conditions from the serializer:

```
class Post
  ...

  def from_last_day
    where('created_at >= ?', 1.day.ago).order created_at: :desc
  end
end
```

Than you could change the `posts_from_last_day` method in the `UserSerializer` to:

```
def posts_from_last_day
  object.posts.from_last_day
end
```

**Update, Part II**

If you don't want `last_post` and `posts_from_last_day` in the same request, you could create two separate serializers:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :last_post # and whatever else you want to be included

  has_many :posts

  def last_post
    object.posts.last
  end
end
```

In the action where you want to retrieve the above data:

```
render json: current_user, serializer: UserSerializer
```

And for the other action you could create the following serializer:

```
class UserLastDaySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :posts_from_last_day # and whatever else you want to be included

  has_many :posts


  def posts_from_last_day
    object.posts.from_last_day
  end
end
```

Which would be called like:

```
render json: current_user, serializer: UserLastDaySerializer
```

Comment: doing this would that return the user data as well?  Being that this is for an api, when calling the routes I need to be able to return the user information, in addition to the posts or last post.

This does give me a bit of help however so thanks for that.  I updated the question with an example result set of what we're looking to achieve.  Eventually I need to figure out how to be able to chain methods together, as i'll be including friends, etc... and posts also has data it'll join as well.

Comment: @Justin I've updated my answer. This should get you in the right direction. Does this help?

Comment: this makes sense and gets me on track to do what I need.  Thank you for the assistance and bearing with my 'noobness' on the subject.  This does bring the question to mind however:  Creating a serializer, it appears as though it automatically called the `from_last_day` and any other methods that are in the attributes.  So, am i correct in that I'd need to create a serializer for each unique result set I want to create?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. Check out **Update, Part II** in my answer.

Comment: Beautiful.  Now last question ( and shouldn't need another update ).  If I didn't want to use initializers would it be considered bad practice to do methods on the post model and within the controller do something like this: 
`user = current_user`
`user[:last_post] = user.posts.last_post` ?  or is something like that even plausible?

Comment: `user` is an instance of the `User` model. In the code `user[:last_post] = user.posts.last_post`, you're assuming the `User` model has an attribute called `last_post` which can be set. You probably don't have that, in which case you would probably get an error like: `can't write unknown attribute last_post`.

Comment: Good to know, and thanks for taking the time to answer my questions and get me on the right track.